# TinyMCE getContent() with default font

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE ver 5.4.2. So far everything good. TinyMCE has the configuration option `content_style` to set default font or other before we set content. It's working on screen but it's not working when we call `getContent()`.

How can we get default font we set it before when we call `getContent()`. It's only working getContent with font if user change the font from toolbar or menu bar.
Is it possible to `getContent()` with default font or fontsize?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#full-featured-non-premium',
    forced_root_block: 'div',
    content_style: "div { font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif; font-size:14px }",
    plugins: ['fullpage save print preview searchreplace autolink directionality',
        'visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template code codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor',
        'toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable',
        'charmap emoticons quickbars'
    ],
    menubar: 'file format',
    menu: {
        file: {
            title: 'File',
            items: 'newdocument | mnuGetContent'
        },
        format: {
            title: 'Format',
            items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript codeformat | formats blockformats fontformats fontsizes align | forecolor backcolor | removeformat'
        },
        insert: {
            title: 'Insert',
            items: 'image link media template codesample inserttable | charmap emoticons hr | pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc | insertdatetime'
        },
    },
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('init',
            function () {                    
                tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<!DOCTYPE HTML"><html><title>this is</title><body><div>Hi World!</div></body></html>', {
                    format: 'html'
                })

            });
        ed.on('BeforeSetContent', function (e) {});
        ed.ui.registry.addMenuItem('mnuGetContent', {
            text: 'Get Content',
            onAction: function () {
                alert(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({
                    format: 'html'
                }))
            }
        });        
    }
});
```

Here is the expected result:

content_style: "div { font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif; font-size:14px }"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML"><html><title>this is</title><body>
<div style="font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif; font-size:14px">Hi World!</div>
</body></html>
```

or

content_style: "body { font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif; font-size:14px }"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML"><html><title>this is</title><body style="font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif; font-size:14px">
<div>Hi World!</div>
</body></html>
```

This is the current result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML"><html><title>this is</title><body>
<div>Hi World!</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE won't do what you are wanting it to do - but I don't know that what you want is actually a good idea.

While editing content, passing in an external style sheet via `content_style` or `content_css` allows you to cleanly separate the semantic content from the styling of that content.  When you use the `getContent()` API call TinyMCE is simply returning to you the content within the `<body>` of the editor - this is its intended behavior.

If you want to inline the CSS into the HTML before you do something with the content (e.g. send as an email) it would make sense to do that right before you use the content for that purpose.  There are tools out there that can do this inlining as this is a common need for sending emails.

If you opt to change the CSS in the future and you inline the CSS when the content is saved you would have to "fix" all the prior content each time you update your CSS.  If you inline the CSS when you choose to use/send the content you maintain the separation of the content from its layout and make it easier to both update the content and change its layout in the future.

Comment: Hi @Michael, Really appreciate for replying to my answer and the details explained. Actually, I'm trying to build some plugin base on TinyMCE. So other developers or our users can use the plugin for sending an email or other purpose. TinyMCE return the content within the <body> is not truth (Maybe I miss understand on this). TinyMCE return the whole HTML if we set "fullpage" plugin at configuration_option. If we can get the content with the default font it will be better for us. I hope the TinyMCE team will consider this function in the next release. As of now, I follow your suggestion. Thank

Comment: @ib3an There exist a lot of APIs that you could piece together to achieve this. In principle you upon the [init event](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/) get the [content body](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getbody) and then use your preffered way to apply inline styles on the iframe's body element. Hope that helps somewhat.